# Finding the taylor series of $f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am working on the following exercise:

> Find the Taylor expansion of the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$ about $z = 3i$.

We had the Taylor Series Theorem in the lecture:

> Let $D \subset \mathbb C$ be a domain and $f: D \to \mathbb C$ a differentiable function. Then $f$ is analytic in $D$ and for any ball $B_R(z_0) \subset D$ the power series expansion
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n
> \end{align*}
>   is valid. Further, if $r \in (0,R)$ then
>   \begin{align*}
> f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{S_r^+(z_0)} \frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)^{n+1}}dw,
> \end{align*}
>   where $S_r^+(z_0) = z_0+re^{it}$ with $0\le t \le 2\pi$.

The solution that I don't understand goes like this: Represent $f$ as partial fractions:
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \left(\frac{1}{z-i} - \frac{1}{z+i}\right).
\end{align*}
Then we compute
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(z) = \left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right)^{(n)} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(z-i)^{n+1}}-\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(z+i)^{n+1}}\right).
\end{align*}
Then one can plug this in the formula and is done.
I don't understand why one can compute so easily the $n$th derivative.

Comment: You just use the quotient rule $n$ times...

Comment: Oh yeah of course. How could I miss that. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use fraction decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive, pretty useful many times, approach:

$$\frac1{1+z^2}=\frac1{10+6i+(z-3i)^2}=\frac1{10+6i}\frac1{1+\left(\frac{z-3i}{\sqrt{10+6i}}\right)^2}$$

Now, notice that

$$\left|\frac{z-3i}{\sqrt{10+6i}}\right|<1\iff|z-3i|^2<|10+6i|=4\sqrt{10}$$

for which values of $\;z\;$ we can write

$$\frac1{1+\left(\frac{z-3i}{\sqrt{10+6i}}\right)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{z-3i}{\sqrt{10+6i}}\right)^n$$

Comment: $10+6i+(z-3i)^2 = 1+6i(1-z)+z^2 \ne 1+z^2$?

Comment: Thanks, how do we know that representation as a series in the last line?

Comment: @numerion It comes from $$\frac1{1+z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^{2n}$$which you can directly calculate it or, if you want, you can elementwise differentiate the powers series of $\;\arctan z\;$

Comment: @DavidHolden: $$(z-3i)^2=z^2-6i-9\;\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio could you give me a broader hint?

Comment: I'm not sure about what, @DavidHolden : $$10+6i+(z-3i)^2=10+6i+z^2-6i-9=1+z^2$$and the above ethe first equality in my answer is, as far as I can see, correct...did you mean anything else?

Comment: @DonAntonio i was just puzzled about what happens to the term $6iz$ in the expansion of $(z-3i)^2$. i.e. $(z-3i)\times(z-3i)=z \times z - z \times 3i - 3i \times z + 3i \times 3i$?

Comment: Yes @David , what you wrote is correct. Since we're in a field multiplication is commutative, so $\;z\cdot 3i=3i\cdot z\;$

Comment: I think there is a typo. The last parenthesis should be raised to $2n$ and not $n$ (as indicated by @DonAntonio in the comment above)

Comment: @DonAntonio david is correct....$(z-3i)^2=z^2-6iz-9\;\ldots$ then why do you write midterm as $6i$ only?...i am still confused

Comment: I think you've got wrong in the middle step, since:
\begin{align} 1+z^2&= 1+z^2+(-6iz+6iz+(3i)^2-(3i)^2) \\
&=1+6iz-(3i)^2+[z^2-6iz+(3i)^2] \\
&=1+6iz-9i^2+[(z-3i)^2] \\
&=10+6iz+[(z-3i)^2] \\
&=(10+6iz)\left(1+\frac{(z-3i)^2}{10+6iz}\right) \\
\end{align}
and then you have a z-term in the denominator and your taylor serie is therefore just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The same function, but the expansion is about $z=1$, solution on page 42. This explanation is for me more clear. https://www.math.ust.hk/~maykwok/courses/ma304/06_07/Complex_5.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Any ideas why $1-i$ was chosen in the second line? I know the fraction simplifies to the previous one.